# Why is PHP script downloaded instead of executed

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have a local LAMP server set up on my Ubuntu laptop for testing various PHP scripts.

Sometimes, when I do something wrong, instead of getting an error, the script I'm testing is offered for download. Why is that and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server does not recognize the script as something to execute locally, and as such it offers it as a file instead.

These lines should be present in your Apache config.  Note that the path may need to be changed for the .so modules, depending on your configuration:

```
# -- if you're using PHP 5, uncomment this line to activate it
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/libphp5.so

# -- if you're using PHP 4, uncomment this line to activate it
#LoadModule php4_module libexec/libphp4.so

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Follow up with a restart of the Apache service and php should load into Apache to run just fine.

Comment: Where to find the apache2 config?

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons I have found that this happens:

- if php is not configured correctly on the server
- if the file doesn't have the correct .php extension
- if it is in a directory that does not allow execution
- if the script takes too long to execute.

One test I use is to make a file in the same directory (verify.php) that contains:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

If that file executes in my browser, it the first 3 points are ok

Comment: Good call,  always have a process to test the environment.  It does not have to be elaborate,  something simple like Brent's verify.php is perfect.

Comment: From my experience, if Apache/PHP are set up correctly, it's usually script execution timeout.

Comment: It's not a script execution timeout in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Avery, that's the usual cause.  However, you specifically say it's only sometimes. Any chance you are changing the content type header?

Comment: No, at least I don't think I am. I was actually working on a WordPress plugin and one minute it was working and after modifying something trivial, I got the download dialog.

Answer (score 0):

A usual error is to print something to the page before the headers get sent.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if you have a .htaccess file in the same folder as your php script, it could be the reason for some execution problems.

For example, if you got a copy of the site files from another server, your htaccess file could have a line like:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php
```

But in your actual server you may be running another version of PHP. So it would not excecute right.