# PHP file gets download instead of getting executed when browsed in any browser

Tags: php5, opensuse

I have a phpinfo.php file which I am trying to run by browsing to it using browser but the browser downloads the file instead of executing it.

**phpinfo.php**

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

I followed following [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/25227/why-is-php-script-downloaded-instead-of-executed) post, added following lines to my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and restarted apache but invain. phpinfo.php still gets downloaded.

> AddType application/x-httpd-php .php> .phtml
>   AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

Have I added these line to the correct file?

On an openSuSE forum following was mentioned. I followed this too but still no success. Same problem is persisting.

> In case the browser wants to save your
>   php files instead of displaying the
>   content, you should enable php support
>   in the /etc/apache2/mod_userdir.conf
>   file. Add the following line to it,
>   just after the  line and restart
>   the server.
>
> Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/php5.conf

Comment: Are you trying to use mod_php or a [F]CGI version?  Make sure whatever instructions you're following matches which php5 package you installed.

Comment: 1) Do you have PHP installed on your system? 2) Do you have this kind of line in your Apache config `LoadModule php5_module libexec/libphp5.so`? In other words -- does Apache knows what module to use to process .php files?

Comment: Well, I installed php using: yast2 -i apache2-mod_php5

Comment: No. Could find this line in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. Also there is no libphp5.so on my system.

Comment: @Usman Here is the general setup instructions: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php -- have a look at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding **php5** to **APACHE_MODULES** in /etc/sysconfig/apache2 and restarting apache solved the problem.