# PHP file not executed

Tags: centos, php5, apache-2.2

I have PHP5 installed on my CentOS 5 server running Apache 2.2.3 (did a yum install)

I ensured the httpd.conf file has all the necessary AddType and LoadModule commands. Even tried restarting httpd.

But when I run a php file, instead of it being executed, the file just downloads. Any ideas what I might be missing?

I did see the different threads returned by Google. Also tried the solutions posted on other similar SF questions ([here](https://serverfault.com/questions/286540/php-file-gets-download-instead-of-getting-executed-when-browsed-in-any-browser) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/25227/why-is-php-script-downloaded-instead-of-executed)) but didn't find a resolution. Tried a manual install of php as well. But php files just don't get executed.

**More on this**

Now I can get the php file to show and not get downloaded. From the httpd.conf, removed the AddType directive and added AddHandler.

On further investigation, if I run a command `php -f my_php_file.php` on my server, the file executes fine. So php installation is not the issue. But somewhere in the configuration file, the mapping is missing (i.e. execute .php files using php). Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Logs, config files... all useful information.

Comment: no error logs generated wrt the files. Which files should I post the content of? httpd.conf, any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wild shot in the dark (since you did not tell us the exact yum command(s) you entered):

I guess you installed PHP CGI/CLI version which needs further configuration to actually work, but what you meant to install was Apache mod_php module. Maybe you installed `php-cli` instead of `php`?

Comment: I ran this command - yum install php. This installs both php and the apache php module (doesn't it)?